# removing NaN from a scipy sparse matrix

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn

I have the following piece of code:

```
input_data = pd.read_csv('file_name.tsv', sep='\t')
data = sparse.csr_matrix(data.values)
model = TruncatedSVD(n_components=2)
model.fit(data)
```

Now TruncatedSVD does take sparse matrices from scipy but it does not take NaN. I expected the crs_matrix function to strip NaN but it does not and I can't find a way to strip these NaN's from my scipy matrix.

Is there a good way to do this? I can't find a function within scipy.

Comment: you just want to set instances of `np.nan` to zero?

Comment: You can't really *remove* NaNs, you can only replace them. Since you use sparse matrices in the same context I believe this is a [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please tell us *why* you want to remove the NaNs. "Because TruncatedSVD does not like them" is not good enough as reason. You need to know what the NaNs *mean* in your data. Otherwise there is no way to tell how to correctly handle them.

Comment: The whole problem is that the Nan datpoints are unknown and there are actual zero values, truncatedSVD actually gives an error if you pass it Nan or inf values.

Comment: @FlorianEn Yep, TruncatedSVD does not know what to do with unknown values. Removing NaNs from a sparse matrix representation is equivaluent to setting them to zero, which is apparently not what you want to achieve. Have a look at [Imputation of missing values](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#imputation-of-missing-values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting the NaNs to zero, this is not the optimal solution but I don't think there really is a satisfying way to impute the missing values in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

There are some approaches to this. One of which you chose - setting the NaNs to zero, other way may be to set them equal to the mean value of your data (column, let's say).

An easy way to adress this is with scikit imputer

```
from sklearn.reprocessing import Imputer

data_imputer = Imputer(missing_values='NaN, strategy='mean', axis=0)
# fit the imputer - suppose missing data is in the 0th column
data_imputer = data_imputer.fit(data[:, 0])
# transform the data
data[:, 0] = data_imputer.transform(X[:, 0])
```

Note that this is a very simple example and can be improved a lot, for more info, see [scikit-learn doc documentation about this issue](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_missing_values.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-missing-values-py).